# Why is my WinUI 3.0 app icon really small?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winui-3

**Small App Icon**:
[image: small app icon in windows 11 start menu]

**Expected Size**:
[image: expected size]

- I am making a WinUI 3.0 app on .NET 8.0
- I have added a custom app icon, and generated all sizes for the icon (in the `Package.appxmanifest` file). The icon appears really small in the start menu *app description* section here.
- It appears perfectly as a pinned app in the start menu and the taskbar though.

What do I do?

**OS - Windows 11**

Comment: The packaging project use `App Icon scale 100` as default. You can set the default Qualifiers. See [Tailor your resources for language, scale, high contrast, and other qualifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast). It works for me.

Comment: You can **Generate** all assets at `Package.appxmanifest` firstly to see if it works fine with unchecking **Apply recommended padding** as @RiteshPatel answered.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate all icons, uncheck **Apply recommended padding**.
If this does not work...
Create 1240 X 1240 icon and from that create all other size icons using Paint or Paint3D. This will sure work. Creating all Recommended icons and 256, 48, 24 and 16 pixels icons will work.